# How to change the title after clicking on a div

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$('.showlink').click( function() {
    $('.box').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.box {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showlink">click</div>
<div class="box">content</div>
```

I have my code like this and I want to change the word '`click`' into '`click again'` that's in the first div after clicking on it, but I don't know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text()` method like following to change text.

```js
$('.showlink').click( function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    $(this).text(text == 'click' ? 'click again' : 'click');
    $('.box').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.box {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showlink">click</div>

<div class="box">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.text method of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2)

```js
 $('.showlink').click(function() {
   $(this).text("Click again");
   $('.box').slideToggle(300);
 });
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showlink">click</div>

<div class="box">content</div>
```

But you can get a bit speed/performance by modifying a bit your JS code. Here you use jQuery to select your DOM nodes each time you click. Since [DOM access is really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817093/but-whys-the-browser-dom-still-so-slow-after-10-years-of-effort) you can save the reference into a variable

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var $showLink = $('.showlink');
  var $box = $('.box');
  $showLink.click(function() {
    $showLink.text("Click again");
    $box.slideToggle(300);
  });

})();
```

```css
 .box {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showlink">click</div>

<div class="box">content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Azim's answer sums it up. But since some new developers don't understand how ternary operations work, you can achieve it with the old fashioned if else statement as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="showlink">click</div>
<div class="box">content</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".box").hide();
$(".showlink").click(function(){
    $(".box").toggle();
  if($(".showlink").click){
    $(".showlink").text("click again");
  } if ($(".box").css("display") == "none") {
    $(".showlink").text("click");
  }
});
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/wp9051eL/)